# How can I call code from a Flutter Plugin?

Tags: flutter, mobile

When I add a plugin in Android Studio to a Flutter App like:

File -> New -> New Module -> Flutter Plugin

the library root myplugin will be created

in myplugin/lib/myplugin.dart the class MyPlugin and function platformVersion is created.

How can I call MyPlugin.platformVersion or interact or use classes in the plugin from my flutter App?

I can't import it like
import 'package:myplugin/...'

and when I use MyPlugin.platformVersion I just get an error with the suggestion:
'create class MyPlugin' not import ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you imported the plugin in your pubspec file?

```
dependencies:
  ...
  myplugin:
    path: ../myplugin/
```

Take a look here for more information
https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/using-packages#dependencies-on-unpublished-packages